# Nesting data in an express app with postgres

Tags: javascript, arrays, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

So I'm new to express and have been playing around with a program where you can create events and invite other users.  I know that you can use join tables to get the data, but I was hoping that there is a way to have the data nest itself using POSTGRESQL to show the events that the user is hosting, attending, and invited to based on the id of an event.

Here is what I have so far:

```
app.get('/api/users', function(req, res) {
var list = [];
User.findAll().then(function(users) {
  for( var i in users) {
    var item = {
      id:         users[i].dataValues['id'],
      firstName:  users[i].dataValues['firstname'],
      lastName:   users[i].dataValues['lastname'],
      email:      users[i].dataValues['email'],
      phone:      users[i].dataValues['phone'],
      image:      users[i].dataValues['image'],
      confirmed:  users[i].dataValues['confirmed'],
      events: []
    }
    Event.findAll({ where: { hosting_id: user.id }}).then(function(events) {
      for( var i in events) {
        item.events.push({
          hosting: event[i].dataValues['id'],
          attending: event[i].dataValues['id'],
          invites: event[i].dataValues['id']
        })
      }
    })
    list.push(item)
  }
  res.json(list)
 })
});
```

I've been able to have it so that it loops and can find all the events that are associated with the user through id, but I'm still struggling with how to have it connect with each one so that it can display the event id, like the following example:

```
{
"id": "4",
"firstName": "Jon",
"lastName": "Doe",
"email": "jdoe@test.com",
"phone": "1234567890",
"image": "",
"events": {
  "hosting": [
    "1"],
  "attending": [],
  "invites": [
    "3", "4"]
    },
"confirmed": true
}
```

Besides having the info displayed, I'm also trying to figure out if it will need to be nested within a POSTGRES database, or if I can just use something like a join table but still have the info display without having another API call.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Event.findAll is a Promise and run asynchronously.
You need to make sure that you format your response only after that call.

You can try something like this and see if it works:

```
Promise.all(
  users.map(function(user) {
    return Event.findaAll({ where: { hosting_id: user.id }})
      .then(function(events) {
        var formatEvents = events.map(function(event) {
          return {
            hosting: event.id,
            attending: event.id,
            invites: event.id
          };
        })
        return Promise.resolve({
          id:         users[i].dataValues['id'],
          firstName:  users[i].dataValues['firstname'],
          lastName:   users[i].dataValues['lastname'],
          email:      users[i].dataValues['email'],
          phone:      users[i].dataValues['phone'],
          image:      users[i].dataValues['image'],
          confirmed:  users[i].dataValues['confirmed'],
          events:     formatEvents
        });
      })
  })
)
  .then(function(list) {
    res.json(list)
  })
```

Or you can also add a relationship between Users and Events and when get users include the events model.